# symfony: fzTag-Pugin, Doctrine: retrieve Tags in template

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

So im Using the fzTag plugin which implements a "taggable" extension to Doctrine models.

In My Action i have something like:

```
      $this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('BlogEntry',5);
      $this->pager->setQuery(Doctrine::getTable('BlogEntry')->createQuery('a')->leftJoin('a.Tags t')->where('t.id = ?',$this->tag->getId()));
      $this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
      $this->pager->init();
```

and in my Template i use:

```
 <?php foreach ($blogentry->getTags() as $tag): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo url_for('blog_tags',$tag) ?>"><?php echo $tag->getName() ?></a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But in the Template $blogentry->getTags() returns just one Tag? How can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve BlogEntries, but still read all it's tags, I usually use subquery, which points me to proper entries.

So, after having your query prepared, like for the usual BlogEntry list, you just add this where condition:

```
$query->where($query->getRootAlias().'.id IN (
                    SELECT b1.id FROM BlogEntry b1 LEFT JOIN b1.Tags t1
                    WHERE t1.id = ? )', $this->tag->getId());
```

Of course, it's best to keep it in your BlogEntryTable class.